# Find the changes over time in a specific code section using git

Tags: git

I want to take a look at how a section of code (a method for example) has changed over time.  I can use `git blame` to find the most recent change of each line then look at the diff of that commit, but what I really want is to see the code evolve over multiple commits.

Basically what I want is `git whatchanged` filtered by line numbers. Basically something like the following imaginary command:

```
git whatchanged <filename>:<start-range>...<end-range>
```

Ideally this would be possible through git directly, but I've been thinking about writing a script to filter the output of `git whatchanged`

Comment: git blame has the `-L` option. And if you use git gui to show the blame, you can click on commits to show them – that way you can more or less go back in history.

Comment: this is a good tip, I didn't know about the `-L` option.  I'd still like to be able to see a summary of changes over time similar to `git whatchanged`

Comment: This would be great. I think this will be a lot more useful than git blame since it seems like blame just shows for latest code so there isn't much way to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `git gui blame`? This interface makes it easy to step back (by clicking the links on the left) to see how the file has changed over time.